# Web scraping sports odds with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm becoming familiar with web scraping and started working on a personal project to automatically bet on some sites. My problem is that in some cases the pages use JavaScript and other complex codes, so I do not get any results. The site I'm dedicating to is "Intralot.it". I opened the page with Chrome and then I looked for the 'class' of my interest 
[(See Chrome inspector)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHBgv.png).
Finally, I tried to get the data using Selenium, but almost always I do not get anything (empty list). Only sometimes, inexplicably, the lists contain data. I would like someone to help me understand what happens and why I'm wrong. Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


link = 'https://www.intralot.it/scommesse/ma/calcio/premier_league/ref?code=1_86#989_9497_0'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)

Teams = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'evento')
Odds  = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//td[class = "quota group_1 ui- 
selectee"]//text()')   

for x in range (0,len(Teams)): print(Teams[x].text)
for y in range (0,len(Odds)): print(Odds[y])
```

Comment: The link is not working for me. Can you post HTML of your needed elements?

Comment: Though the [url](https://www.intralot.it/scommesse/ma/calcio/serie/ref?%20code=1_86#989_9497_0) opens but no data is present on the webpage at my side. Is there any additional steps to see the data?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I have updated the link, now it works. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following CSS Selectors for your list of elements:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


Teams = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.evento")))
Odds = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr > td:nth-child(2)")))

for x,y in zip(Teams, Odds):

    print x.text, y.text
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ratmir , the code works but not always. The problem is that if (for example) I run the program three times, the first time I get the data from the page and the other two do not (or maybe not). It seems that the web page is updated in a particular way, and that Selenium can not synchronize correctly ....

Comment: @Mark.Doe, I think you need to use explicit waits. Can you try my updated answer? Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! You can accept my answer (check a tick near my answer). Thanks.